# Vue.js: импорт директив и подключение их через конструктор Vue

Tags: vue.js

Пытаюсь провести рефакторинг проекта. Дошли руки до директив. Изначально объявлял их через метод Vue.directive(), но теперь решил вынести в отдельные файл. Но чет не работает - Vue их не видит. Аналогичным образом пытаюсь поступить и с миксинами. В чем моя ошибка? Вообще возможно ли такая задумка?

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import directives from './directives'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    directives
})

// Vue.directive('inputmask', {
//     bind: (el, binding) => {
//         Inputmask(binding.value).mask(el)
//     }
// })
```

directives.js

```
const directives = {
    inputmask: {
        bind: (el, binding) => {
            Inputmask(binding.value).mask(el)
        }
    }
}

export default directives
```

Comment: Так какой смысл все директивы только к корневому компоненту подключать... изначально было правильно, зря поломал. В один файл - возможно, но опять же, это выглядит бессмысленным (реализацию директив стоит размещать в отдельных файлах, например в `src/plugins/directives/`).

Comment: Вот от глобальной регистрации (`Vue.directive`) избавиться, _иногда_ есть смысл: когда директива нужна только локально, вполне логично ее импортировать и подключать локально в компоненте. Но чаще, глобальная регистрация удобнее, из-за того что директивы все равно выполняются только при их использовании. Локальное подключение бывает нужным разве что при конфликтах имен или при попытке заполиморфить директиву наименее удобным способом из возможных (других юзкейсов по-моему не бывает).